# New Prime Sieve Algorithm Omitting 2 and 5 Is it flawed?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have developed a new algorithm.

Arithmetic Sequence f(n)=3+(10*n) (Where f(n) are candidate Primes)

Array P, with P(1)=3 (Where P is the array filled with primes with an index number).

Set candidate as f(n)

Try to divide candidate by all P

Result 1: if candidate is not divisible by any P

```
 Action 1: add candidate to P. Increment n by 1
```

Result 2: if candidate is divisible by any P

```
   Action 2: set candidate to candidate / (P by which candidate could be divided), then
   repeat rule 1 with the new candidate.
```

Result 3: if candidate is divisible by any P and
the result equals 1.

```
    Action 3: increment n by 1.
```

Here is an example:

f(0) = 3 Result 3 P1 = 3

f(1) = 13 Result 1. P2=13

f(2) = 23 Result 1. P3=23

f(3) = 33 Result 2. new candidate = 11. Result 1. P4 = 11.

f(4) = 43 Result 1. P5 = 43

f(5) = 53 Result 1. P6 = 53

f(6) = 63 Result 2. new candidate = 21. Result 2. new candidate = 7. Result 1. P7 = 7

f(7) = 73 Result 1. P8 = 73

f(8) = 83 Result 1. P9 = 83

f(9) = 93 Result 2. new candidate = 31. Result 1. P10 = 31.

f(10) = 103 Result 1. P11 = 103.

f(11) = 113 Result 1. P12 = 113.

f(12) = 123 Result 2. new candidate = 41. Result 1. P13 = 41.

f(13) = 133 Result 2. new candidate = 19. Result 1. P14 = 19.

f(14) = 143 Result 2. new candidate = 13. Result 3.

And so on...

I claim that this algorithm finds all primes except 2 and 5, but I have no formal proof. Can anyone show that this algorithm adds non-primes to array P or that it omits primes (except for 2 and 5) from this list?

Comment: What do you mean with "all primes" ? You can only check the primes upto some limit.

Comment: I mean that if you let n go to infinity it will not skip any primes. (In this algorithm the order depends on the last digit. For example you find prime numbers ending on a 3 faster than you find primes ending on a 1 and primes ending on a 7 and primes ending on a 9. The order of occurrence is 3, 1, 7, 9. What I mean to say is this: 11, 31, 41,61, 71 are the only primes ending on 1 up to 71 and this algorithm will not miss any of them.

Comment: If I understand it right, the algorithm finds, in particular, the smallest prime divisor of every number of the form $10k+3$. And it can easily be shown that for every prime $p>5$, there is a $k$ with $p|10k+3$ and $p$ is the smallest prime factor. So the algorithm should find all primes, but in a very inefficient way for large numbers because trial division is used.

Comment: I understand, does this mean that this algorithm will function correctly? ( I do have more optimized versions of this algorithm) Particularly where trial division is eliminated or minimized.

Comment: Yes, I think it actually works in principal.

Comment: Would you be interested in checking an optimized version of this algorithm and could I contact you? (How?) (I have been stuck on parallel programming) but basically, as the numbers become larger the new version takes less and less time to determine the next prime.

Comment: Why do you want to use this new algorithm instead of well-known algorithms such as Sieve of Erathostenes. Do you have a reason to believe that your algorithm finds the primes faster ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63543/discussion-between-st-clair-bij-and-peter).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388023/new-prime-sieve-omitting-2-and-5-how-to-declare-dependency-of-rule-3-on-rule-2